# Jquery spinner not stopping in IE 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
   jQuery(function($){
       $( ".reg" ).click(function() {
           $('#loginBg').block({ message: $('#loader') });
       });
   });


<div id='loader' style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:      100%;border:none;display: none;">
<img src="../img/ajax-loader_transparent.gif"/>
```

The above code works fine with other browsers.

But the spinner is not stopping in IE 10 and 11.

Comment: What is `block`, a plugin?

Comment: You need to call `unblock` at the moment/event you want the spinner to stop. Could you provide the code (with some context: an Ajax callback, or event handler) where you use it? With the code you provided so far, the spinner would not stop in any browser. Did you close the loader `div` tag?

Comment: Yes..it is a plugin...

Comment: div tag is also closed...i use the block function here.<h:commandButton value="#{msg.submit}" styleClass="btn btn-purple btn-lg btn-block reg" action="#{registrationBean.registerAction}">
                           </h:commandButton>